# Is it idomatic to drop pronouns when using semi colons in German?

Tags: grammar-identification, grammar-style

> Ich kann mich nicht mehr mit Menschen verbinden; ~~ich~~ bin so einsam

I had written the sentence without the ich (second part). Is this allowed in German? The idea I have is that the comma works as a semi colon, and with the verb conjugation, it would be clear that I am talking about myself in the second part.

Comment: "The comma works as a semi colon" - this is just confusing. A comma is a comma and a semicolon is a semicolon. If you want the effect of a semicolon, why don't you use one?

Comment: "Ich verbinde mich mit Menschen" isn't exactly idiomatic. A native speaker would rather say "Ich finde keinen Kontakt zu Menschen" or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you use comma, semicolon or period is a choice of style, somewhat indicating how close the author relates the two sentences. Each is valid as both sentences are independent main clauses.

Strictly formal the 'ich' of the 2nd sentence is required. However in spoken colloquial language it can be left out as it can be inferred from context. I would never leave it out in written language unless I intend to mimic or quote spoken language.

The statements of these two paragraphs above are valid completely independently.

Answer (score 1):

You ask whether this is idiomatic and whether it is allowed. These are different questions (and “allowed” may not be the best word here, but I think it is clear what you mean). Also “mich mit Menschen verbinden” is a bit awkward, but I will not try to find a better wording.

> Ich kann mich nicht mehr mit Menschen verbinden, bin so einsam.

I think most people would not normally say or write this. However, this can be seen as an “Aufzählung” of the two parts “kann mich nicht mehr mit Menschen verbinden” und “bin so einsam”. I think that this is correct grammar and punctuation. You could replace the comma with “und”. However, this way of analysing the sentence would be an argument against a semicolon.